# Are there non-contractible spaces $A$ and $B$ such that $A \wedge B$ is contractible?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

The question is in the title : Can we find spaces $A$ and $B$, each non contractible, such that their smash product $A \wedge B$, i.e. the homotopy cofibre of $A \vee B \to A \times B$, is a contractible space ?

Comment: Maybe. Take $A=S^1$ and $B$ the classifying space of a group with trivial homology, but I don't know if these exist.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: there are many groups with trivial homology.  There is a general construction as part of the proof of the Kan-Thurston theorem, for example.

Answer (score 8):

Oh yes ! Fernando gave the hint !
Take $A = S^1$ and $B$ = the Epstein's space.
Then $A \wedge B \simeq \Sigma B$ is contractible but $B$ is not !

Comment: What's the Epstein's space?

Comment: Here is the reference for Epstein's space :
D.B.A.Epstein, "A group with zero homology",
Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society 64(03):599 - 602 · July 1968

Comment: Thank you. From your comment, I understand that Epstein's space is the classifying space for a certain group.

Answer (score 6):

I just saw this in Ravenel's "orange book"! Let $X$ be any simply connected CW complex whose reduced homology is all torsion. Let $X_{(p)}$ be the p-localization for a prime $p$. Then for primes $p\neq q$, $X_{(p)}\wedge X_{(q)}$ is contractible. But neither $X_{(p)}$ nor $X_{(q)}$ is contractible if $H_*(X)$ has $p$ and $q$ torsion.

Comment: In the same spirit, just take the smash product of two CW complexes that are Moore spaces for finite cyclic groups of relatively prime orders.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's much simpler :-)